# How do I receive a file path in my app which is invoked as a service in os x?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I proceeded to create an OS X application and register a service (i.e. right-click menu option on files in Finder), and everything works, except the OS does not seem to be sending a legible file path to my app when I right-click a file in Finder and select my "Open with MyProgram" custom option.

My receiving handler:

```
- (void)doSomething:(NSPasteboard *)pboard userData:(NSString *)userData error:(NSString **)error {
NSString *pboardString = [pboard stringForType:NSStringPboardType];
NSLog(@"I hope the file path is: %@", pboardString);
}
```

With the above code, pboardString will actually contain odd stuff like: "file:///.file/id=6562758.3327676"

Which may be junk, or may be translatable to something useful; I don't know. I get hex results like <NSPasteboardItem: 0x103b37d90> if I try to print the pasteboard object as an array.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with service properties (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/properties.html), but if anyone knows what I'm missing I'd appreciate the guidance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the file paths by looking at [NSPasteboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s  propertyListForType:

And use NSFilenamesPboardType

```
- (void)doSomething:(NSPasteboard *)pboard userData:(NSString *)userData error:(NSString **)error {

    NSArray *files = [pboard propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
    NSLog(@"I hope the file path is files: %@", files);

}
```

You should read the documentation I have linked to above

Comment: Perfect. I started working with Obj-C about a week ago.. wasn't even sure how to find all the other stuff hiding in the pasteboard. Wasn't sure there WAS other stuff hiding in it!

Comment: Here is a video showing one way to find out that stuff. I admit the video is a little experiment of mine to see how I can post them on my blog. But it should be helpful if you don't know the tip already. http://www.markosx.com/thecocoaquest/videos-2/videos/